# Problema con interfaz gráfica

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo este dilema sobre la ubicación de botones y demases en `android` que hace que se encuentren en distintas ubicaciones los botones. A modo de ejemplo, tengo una pantalla con un `VideoView` y por encima de esta un `Button` **(saltar)** en `Xiaomi` se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve en `Motorola/Samsung`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es como tengo el `layout` de dicha `activity`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".IntroVideo.VideoIntroduccion">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/introVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSaltarVideo"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_saltarvideo"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="Saltar"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="345dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este inconveniente? Desde ya, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debes usar margin para alinear tus componentes hacia la derecha, esto causa que en pantallas delgadas el botón se salga de la pantalla y en modo landscape posiblemente tu botón aparece al centro. Para lograr lo que buscas puedes usar FrameLayout y el atributo layout_gravity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".IntroVideo.VideoIntroduccion">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/introVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSaltarVideo"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_saltarvideo"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Saltar"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

podrías dar un margen mas pequeño y el tema de la posicion dejarselo a las propiedades que te proporciona el `RelativeLayout`, usa `layout_alignParentRight` y `layout_alignParentTop`, la primera propiedad te coloca el boton a la derecha de su ViewGroup padre y la segunda coloca verticalmente, justo en el lado superior de su `ViewGroup`.

Si quieres espacio a los lados de tu `View` , puedes dar `layout_marginTop` y `layout_marginBottom` si lo deseas.

Tu botón quedaría así:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/btnSaltarVideo"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_saltarvideo"/>
```